Latex Cover Page
I am trying to do a cover page in B5 size, but there is an extra page on top of my page. My latex is:
\documentclass[oneside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ean13isbn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={,
10.5in},spine=1in,cropmarks,textwidth=7in,leftmargin=0in,nopagenumbers,color]{zwpagelayout}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pagecolor{purple}
\color{white}

% Creating the cover layout with three sections: Front, Spine, Back
\noindent
% Front cover
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][t]{0.45\textwidth} % Front cover - 45% of the page width
    \vspace*{3cm} % Adjust vertical alignment to bring text down slightly
    \centering
    {\Huge \textbf{Μεθοδολογικοί Παράγοντες Εκτίμησης της Αληθότητας \\ των Ενδοστοματικών Σαρωτών}}\\[1.5cm]
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.495cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line under the title
    {\large Η οδοντιατρική επιστημονική κοινότητα έχει σημειώσει σημαντική πρόοδο στην ανάπτυξη ψηφιακών εργαλείων για τη μέτρηση της ακρίβειας των αποκαταστάσεων που πραγματοποιούνται με τη βοήθεια της τεχνολογίας \selectlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM}\selectlanguage{greek} και συστημάτων ενδοστοματικής σάρωσης. Οι περισσότερες μελέτες που έχουν δημοσιευτεί μέχρι σήμερα χρησιμοποιούν αρχεία \selectlanguage{english}{STL}\selectlanguage{greek} από ενδοστοματικούς σαρωτές για να συγκρίνουν την αληθότητα και την ακρίβεια ψηφιακών και συμβατικών αποτυπωμάτων. Ωστόσο, τα αποτελέσματα των ερευνών ποικίλλουν, με κάποιες μελέτες να δείχνουν υπεροχή της ψηφιακής αποτύπωσης και άλλες να παρουσιάζουν χαμηλότερη ακρίβεια σε σχέση με τις παραδοσιακές μεθόδους. Αυτή η διαφοροποίηση μπορεί να αποδοθεί σε διάφορους παράγοντες, όπως η τεχνολογία του σαρωτή, το μήκος της σαρωμένης περιοχής, οι συνθήκες φωτισμού, η εμπειρία του χειριστή και η ακρίβεια των αλγορίθμων που χρησιμοποιούνται για την ευθυγράμμιση των αρχείων \selectlanguage{english}{STL}\selectlanguage{greek}. Σημαντική είναι επίσης η συσχέτιση της ακρίβειας των σαρώσεων με την τελική ποιότητα των οδοντικών αποκαταστάσεων, είτε αυτές είναι \selectlanguage{english}{3D}\selectlanguage{greek} εκτυπωμένες είτε προϊόν μηχανικής κατεργασίας. Το σφάλμα \selectlanguage{english}{RMS (Root Mean Square)}\selectlanguage{greek} αποτελεί το βασικό εργαλείο μέτρησης, καθώς επιτρέπει τη σύγκριση της ακρίβειας ανάμεσα στα ψηφιακά μοντέλα και τις φυσικές αποκαταστάσεις. Οι έρευνες δείχνουν ότι η μείωση του σφάλματος \selectlanguage{english}{RMS (Root Mean Square)}\selectlanguage{greek} συμβάλλει σημαντικά στη βελτίωση της ποιότητας των οδοντιατρικών εργασιών και στην ικανοποίηση των ασθενών. \\ Συνολικά, ο στόχος αυτής της μελέτης είναι η διερεύνηση των παραγόντων που επηρεάζουν την ακρίβεια των ενδοστοματικών σαρωτών, όπως το μήκος της σαρωμένης περιοχής, ο αριθμός των σημείων ευθυγράμμισης και η εμπειρία του χειριστή. \\ Σκοπός της ερευνητικής μονογραφίας είναι να αποτρέψει τον ερευνητή να κάνει λάθη που θα αποβούν σημαντικά στη μέτρηση της αληθότητας των ενδοστοματικών σαρωτών.}
    
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line above the ISBN
    {\large ISBN: 123-456-789-1011-12-13}
\end{minipage}%
% Spine
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][t]{0.11\textwidth} % Spine - 11% of the page width
    \centering
    \vspace*{-2cm} % Adjust vertical alignment for spine text to bring it more central
    \rotatebox{90}{\Huge \textbf{Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης}}\\
    \vspace*{1cm}
    \rotatebox{90}{\Large Πέτρος Μουρούζης, 2024}
\end{minipage}%
% Back cover
\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][t]{0.425\textwidth} % Back cover - 42.5% of the page width
    \vspace*{3cm} % Adjust vertical alignment
    \centering
    {\Huge Μεθοδολογικοί Παράγοντες Εκτίμησης της Αληθότητας των \\ Ενδοστοματικών Σαρωτών}\\[1.5cm]
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line under the title
    {\large Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης \\ Εργαστήριο Οδοντικής Χειρουργικής \\ Τομέας Παθολογίας και Θεραπευτικής των Οδοντικών Ιστών}
    \vspace*{2cm}
    \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line above the author details
    {\Large Ερευνητική Μονογραφία \\[\baselineskip] Πέτρος Μουρούζης \\ Επίκουρος Καθηγητής Α.Π.Θ.} \\
    \vspace*{4cm} % Adjust to make sure the place and date are visible
    {\scshape ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ \\ 17 ΔΕΚΕΜΒΡΙΟΥ 2024}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}



Overfull \vbox (4.9939pt too high) has occurred while \output is active [] this is pushing your content to the next page.

Note that you might add unwanted spaces before the first minipage if you have empty lines and lines not ending with % in your code. Unrelated: It seems that you should add a \par every time you use a construction like {\large foo bar} so that it becomes {\large foo bar \par}. Otherwise you get bad line spacing.

For spine and backpage change to .8\textheight for the minipages. They cause a newpage.

@yannisl isn't shrinking the cover by 20% rather a large sledge hammer for a nut of only 5pt?

@cfr  There was a lot of room so I just put the 20% to demo and demonstrate. It worked.

Replace [t] with [] as the first argument to your minipages. To see the problem compile, for example,
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Abc \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t][5cm][t]{5cm}
  % don't do this!
  \vspace*{1cm}
  \centering
  {\Huge
  Abc}\\
  def
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}


\documentclass[oneside,notitlepage]{book}
\usepackage[a3paper,landscape,margin=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{ean13isbn}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[papersize={,
10.5in},spine=1in,cropmarks,textwidth=7in,leftmargin=0in,nopagenumbers,color]{zwpagelayout}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}\pagecolor{purple}\color{white}%
% Creating the cover layout with three sections: Front, Spine, Back
\noindent
% Front cover
\begin{minipage}[][\textheight][t]{0.45\textwidth} % Front cover - 45% of the page width
  \vspace*{3cm} % Adjust vertical alignment to bring text down slightly
  \centering
  {\Huge \textbf{Μεθοδολογικοί Παράγοντες Εκτίμησης της Αληθότητας \\ των Ενδοστοματικών Σαρωτών}}\\[1.5cm]
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.495cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line under the title
  {\large Η οδοντιατρική επιστημονική κοινότητα έχει σημειώσει σημαντική πρόοδο στην ανάπτυξη ψηφιακών εργαλείων για τη μέτρηση της ακρίβειας των αποκαταστάσεων που πραγματοποιούνται με τη βοήθεια της τεχνολογίας \selectlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM}\selectlanguage{greek} και συστημάτων ενδοστοματικής σάρωσης. Οι περισσότερες μελέτες που έχουν δημοσιευτεί μέχρι σήμερα χρησιμοποιούν αρχεία \selectlanguage{english}{STL}\selectlanguage{greek} από ενδοστοματικούς σαρωτές για να συγκρίνουν την αληθότητα και την ακρίβεια ψηφιακών και συμβατικών αποτυπωμάτων. Ωστόσο, τα αποτελέσματα των ερευνών ποικίλλουν, με κάποιες μελέτες να δείχνουν υπεροχή της ψηφιακής αποτύπωσης και άλλες να παρουσιάζουν χαμηλότερη ακρίβεια σε σχέση με τις παραδοσιακές μεθόδους. Αυτή η διαφοροποίηση μπορεί να αποδοθεί σε διάφορους παράγοντες, όπως η τεχνολογία του σαρωτή, το μήκος της σαρωμένης περιοχής, οι συνθήκες φωτισμού, η εμπειρία του χειριστή και η ακρίβεια των αλγορίθμων που χρησιμοποιούνται για την ευθυγράμμιση των αρχείων \selectlanguage{english}{STL}\selectlanguage{greek}. Σημαντική είναι επίσης η συσχέτιση της ακρίβειας των σαρώσεων με την τελική ποιότητα των οδοντικών αποκαταστάσεων, είτε αυτές είναι \selectlanguage{english}{3D}\selectlanguage{greek} εκτυπωμένες είτε προϊόν μηχανικής κατεργασίας. Το σφάλμα \selectlanguage{english}{RMS (Root Mean Square)}\selectlanguage{greek} αποτελεί το βασικό εργαλείο μέτρησης, καθώς επιτρέπει τη σύγκριση της ακρίβειας ανάμεσα στα ψηφιακά μοντέλα και τις φυσικές αποκαταστάσεις. Οι έρευνες δείχνουν ότι η μείωση του σφάλματος \selectlanguage{english}{RMS (Root Mean Square)}\selectlanguage{greek} συμβάλλει σημαντικά στη βελτίωση της ποιότητας των οδοντιατρικών εργασιών και στην ικανοποίηση των ασθενών. \\ Συνολικά, ο στόχος αυτής της μελέτης είναι η διερεύνηση των παραγόντων που επηρεάζουν την ακρίβεια των ενδοστοματικών σαρωτών, όπως το μήκος της σαρωμένης περιοχής, ο αριθμός των σημείων ευθυγράμμισης και η εμπειρία του χειριστή. \\ Σκοπός της ερευνητικής μονογραφίας είναι να αποτρέψει τον ερευνητή να κάνει λάθη που θα αποβούν σημαντικά στη μέτρηση της αληθότητας των ενδοστοματικών σαρωτών.}

  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line above the ISBN
  {\large ISBN: 123-456-789-1011-12-13}
\end{minipage}%
% Spine
\begin{minipage}[][\textheight][t]{0.11\textwidth} % Spine - 11% of the page width
  \centering
  \vspace*{-2cm} % Adjust vertical alignment for spine text to bring it more central
  \rotatebox{90}{\Huge \textbf{Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης}}\\
  \vspace*{1cm}
  \rotatebox{90}{\Large Πέτρος Μουρούζης, 2024}
\end{minipage}%
% Back cover
\begin{minipage}[][\textheight][t]{0.425\textwidth} % Back cover - 42.5% of the page width
  \vspace*{3cm} % Adjust vertical alignment
  \centering
  {\Huge Μεθοδολογικοί Παράγοντες Εκτίμησης της Αληθότητας των \\ Ενδοστοματικών Σαρωτών}\\[1.5cm]
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line under the title
  {\large Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης \\ Εργαστήριο Οδοντικής Χειρουργικής \\ Τομέας Παθολογίας και Θεραπευτικής των Οδοντικών Ιστών}
όπως η τεχνολογία του σαρωτή, το μήκος της σαρωμένης περιοχής, οι συνθήκες φωτισμού, η εμπειρία του χειριστή και η ακρίβεια των αλγορίθμων που χρησιμοποιούνται για την ευθυγράμμιση των αρχείων \selectlang
uage{english}{STL}\selectlanguage{greek}. Σημαντική είναι επίσης η συσχέτιση της ακρίβειας των σαρώσεων με την τελική ποιότητα των οδοντικών αποκαταστάσεων, είτε αυτές είναι \selectlanguage{english}{3D}\s
electlanguage{greek} εκτυπωμένες είτε προϊόν μηχανικής κατεργασίας. Το σφάλμα \selectlanguage{english}{RMS (Root Mean Square)}\selectlanguage{greek} αποτελεί το βασικό εργαλείο μέτρησης, καθώς επιτρέπει τ
η σύγκριση της ακρίβειας ανάμεσα στα ψηφιακά μοντέλα και τις φυσικές αποκαταστάσεις. Οι έρευνες δείχνουν ότι η μείωση του σφάλματος \selectlanguage{english}{RMS (Root Mean Square)}\selectlanguage{greek} σ
υμβάλλει σημαντικά στη βελτίωση της ποιότητας των οδοντιατρικών εργασιών και στην ικανοποίηση των ασθενών. \\ Συνολικά, ο στόχος αυτής της μελέτης είναι η διερεύνηση των παραγόντων που επηρεάζουν την ακρί
βεια των ενδοστοματικών σαρωτών, όπως το μήκος της σαρωμένης περιοχής, ο αριθμός των σημείων ευθυγράμμισης και η εμπειρία του χειριστή. \\ Σκοπός της ερευνητικής μονογραφίας είναι να αποτρέψει τον ερευνητ
ή να κάνει λάθη που θα αποβούν σημαντικά στη μέτρηση της αληθότητας των ενδοστοματικών σαρωτών.}

  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line above the ISBN
  {\large ISBN: 123-456-789-1011-12-13}
\end{minipage}%
% Spine
\begin{minipage}[][\textheight][t]{0.11\textwidth} % Spine - 11% of the page width
  \centering
  \vspace*{-2cm} % Adjust vertical alignment for spine text to bring it more central
  \rotatebox{90}{\Huge \textbf{Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης}}\\
  \vspace*{1cm}
  \rotatebox{90}{\Large Πέτρος Μουρούζης, 2024}
\end{minipage}%
% Back cover
\begin{minipage}[][\textheight][t]{0.425\textwidth} % Back cover - 42.5% of the page width
  \vspace*{3cm} % Adjust vertical alignment
  \centering
  {\Huge Μεθοδολογικοί Παράγοντες Εκτίμησης της Αληθότητας των \\ Ενδοστοματικών Σαρωτών}\\[1.5cm]
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line under the title
  {\large Αριστοτέλειο Πανεπιστήμιο Θεσσαλονίκης \\ Εργαστήριο Οδοντικής Χειρουργικής \\ Τομέας Παθολογίας και Θεραπευτικής των Οδοντικών Ιστών}
  \vspace*{2cm}
  \rule{\textwidth}{2pt} \\[0.5cm] % Adding a thicker horizontal line above the author details
  {\Large Ερευνητική Μονογραφία \\[\baselineskip] Πέτρος Μουρούζης \\ Επίκουρος Καθηγητής Α.Π.Θ.} \\
  \vspace*{4cm} % Adjust to make sure the place and date are visible
  {\scshape ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗ \\ 17 ΔΕΚΕΜΒΡΙΟΥ 2024}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


Thank you very much.
